# WLAN Sensitivity setting is not supported

Tags: wireless, networking, drivers, broadcom, 14.10

I need to set and get sensitivity value for WLAN device of my Lenovo machine. I tried to set other settings such as operation mode, txpower and frequency and it works fine.

Machine Manufacturer: Lenovo

O.S: Ubunutu Linux 14.10

WLAN Device: Broadcom

> ```
>     02:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n (rev 01)
>     Subsystem: Lenovo Device 0611
>     Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
>     Memory at b0500000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32K]
>     Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
>     Capabilities: [58] Vendor Specific Information: Len=78<?>
>     Capabilities: [48] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
>     Capabilities: [d0] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
>     Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
>     Capabilities: [13c] Virtual Channel
>     Capabilities: [160] Device Serial Number 00-00-f2-ff-ff-d8-80-56
>     Capabilities: [16c] Power Budgeting<?>
>     Kernel driver in use: wl
> ```

I tried to set sensitivity using ioctl command and using iwconfig as follows:

> ```
>     sudo iwconfig wlan0 sens -80
> ```

however, I received "Operation not Supported" error in both cases.

If I couldn't solve this issue using my machine, do you know if there are different Devices and Device Drivers the support setting and getting sensitivity?